# How to turn this query into a typeorm query

Tags: sql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

How do I transform the query below into a typeorm query? I want to return the count of all the jackets inside each column and have it ordered for a specific board.

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(j.id)
FROM `column` c, jacket j
WHERE c.boardId = 1 AND j.columnId = c.id
GROUP BY j.columnId
```

For these tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `column` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `boardId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (boardId) REFERENCES board(`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jacket` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `columnId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (columnId) REFERENCES `column`(`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution.

```
   const results = await this.connection
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select('column.id')
      .from(Column, 'column')
      .addSelect('COUNT(*)', 'jacketCount')
      .from(Jacket, 'jacket')
      .where('column.boardId = :id', { id: jacketBoardId })
      .where('column.id = jacket.columnId')
      .groupBy('column.id')
      .orderBy('column.position', 'ASC')
      .getRawMany();
```